ASSISTANT API ERROR : Files with extensions [none] are not supported for retrieval
hi i am facing error using assistant api chatgpt-4 when trying to upload files to specific thread using message

Issue summary

i am building exam generator ai that takes files(books) and creates question based on the file content using django drf api

every thing is working smooth i uploaded the file i get file id in console when i log

thread is created but when message tries to access file its error and says : Files with extensions [none] are not supported for retrieval

then i look my storage


storage
it uploads files without extension so when message tries to access the file it can't because it does not have type .

so how can i solve this issue

My code :


from openai import OpenAI
import environ


env =environ.Env()
environ.Env.read_env()

openai_api_key = env("OPENAI_API_KEY")
client = OpenAI(api_key=openai_api_key)


def generate_exam(prompt, the_file):
    assistant_id = env("ASSISTANT_ID")
    thread = client.beta.threads.create()
    print("Thread is created")

    # Upload file to OpenAI
    uploaded_file = client.files.create(file=the_file.read(), purpose='assistants')
    file_id = uploaded_file.id
    print("File is uploaded: " + file_id)

    # Create message with file attachment
    message = client.beta.threads.messages.create(
        thread_id=thread.id,
        role="user",
        content=prompt,  # Use the prompt directly as a string
        attachments=[
            {
                "file_id": file_id,
                "tools": [{"type": "file_search"}]
            }
        ]
    )
    print("Message is created")

    # Create and monitor run
    run = client.beta.threads.runs.create(
        thread_id=thread.id,
        assistant_id=assistant_id,
    )
    print("Run instance is created")

    # Polling for run completion
    while run.status != "completed":
        run = client.beta.threads.runs.retrieve(
            thread_id=thread.id,
            run_id=run.id
        )
        print(f"Run status: {run.status}")

    # Retrieve and display messages after run completion
    messages = client.beta.threads.messages.list(thread_id=thread.id)
    response = ""
    for msg in messages.data:
        if msg.role == "assistant":
            response += msg.content[0].text.value + "\n"
    
    return response if response else "No response generated."


then i look my storage

storage
it uploads files without extension so when message tries to access the file it can't because it does not have type .
